# How to enable i386 architecture on Fedora 30?

Tags: 64-bit, x86-64, 32bit-64bit, fedora, 32-bit

I have installed Fedora 64 bit on VirtualBox for development. I had a toolchain that is of 32bit i386 architecture. How can I enable support for 32 bit arch on Fedora.

I had tried to enable the support on Ubuntu, and was able to do it. But, I am new to fedora and I tried the following commands to enable it, but it doesn't seem to work.

https://www.thalib.in/notes/2017-02-17-32bit-no-such-a-file-or-directory.html

I am not able to find anything like this for Fedora.

Comment: You mean gcc multiarch 32-bit libraries?

Comment: Yes, I guess that's what's needed to run compile the code. That had worked in Ubuntu when I added the architecture and installed the multiarch files.